# Can not access private member variable in .h file from .cpp

Tags: c++, header-files

I am new to C++, and not sure why I cant access return type 
from .cpp that is defined in .h file. When I change Edge::Vertex getVertex1() to Vertex getVertex1() I only get error
error: use of undeclared identifier 'vertex1' (the same for vertex 2 in edge class)
Can someone explain why this approach is not good?

```
// Graph.cpp -- Graph contains main function.
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Edge.h"
#define EDGE_DISTANCE 1 
using namespace std;
class Graph
{        
};

int main()
{
   Vertex v1(0);
   Vertex v2(1);
   Edge edge(v1, v2);

   // cout << edge.getVertex1() << endl;
   // cout << edge.getVertex2() << endl;

   return 0;
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
// Edge.h
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H
#include "Vertex.h"
using namespace std;

class Edge
{
    private:
        Vertex vertex1;
        Vertex vertex2;
        int weight;
    public:
       Edge(Vertex,Vertex);
       Vertex getVertex1();
       Vertex getVertex2();
};
#endif
--------------------------------------------------------------
// Edge.cpp
#include "Edge.h"
Edge::Edge(Vertex _vertex1, Vertex _vertex2)
{
   vertex1 = _vertex1;
   vertex2 = _vertex2;
   weight  = 1;
}

Edge::Vertex getVertex1() // error: no type named 'Vertex' in 'Edge'
{
   return vertex1;        // error: use of undeclared identifier 'vertex1'    
}

Edge::Vertex getVertex2()
{
  return vertex2;
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex.h
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Vertex
{
  private:
      long id;

  public:
      list<Vertex> adjacentVertexes;
      Vertex();
      Vertex(long);
};
#endif
--------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex.cpp
#include "Vertex.h"
Vertex::Vertex(long _id)
{
   id = _id;
}
```

Comment: Does not look like Vertex is in namespace or class Edge.

Comment: Vertex is not defined in Edge, it's a standalone class. Function declaration in C++ should look like this: `return_type function_name (argument list) {body}`, so in your case that would be `Vertex Edge::getVertex1(){//body}`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I was expecting you to make an answer and race with me for the upvotes - in quality I mean, not in speed. Quality counts, speed does not.

Comment: Thank you everyone for fast and clear reply.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do better next time :p

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Why next time? Start now. Shouldn't be too hard to make an answer more helpful than an existing one, and voters might notice that you had the knowledge already in your comment, for breaking a tie. Try to explain better than the answer you consider currently best. Even if it is not mine. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Chocolate Cheesecake?

Comment: Nice idea, but what I actually mean is described in the link I provided. Note that you are not actually required to accept an answer, but if you don't you probably want to explain what is missing in the existing answers, which makes them unhelpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In Edge.cpp, change the following:

```
Edge::Vertex getVertex1()
```

to:

```
Vertex Edge::getVertex1()
Vertex Edge::getVertex2()
```

also you are missing the empty constructor implementation for Vertex.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> error: no type named 'Vertex' in 'Edge'

is quite clear. The type you are trying to use as the return value for the function is not in a namespace or class named "Edge".
On the other hand, in order to define a method of class Edge in a separate code file instead of inside the class declaration, you need to start with the class name. That will also fix the second error, because if you make a method implementation for the class (instead of a stanadalone function) it will be able to access the private attribute.

So change this

```
Edge::Vertex getVertex1()
```

to

```
Vertex Edge::getVertex1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is off: it should be `<return type> <class>::<memberfuction>`

`Edge::Vertex getVertex1()` should be `Vertex Edge::getVertex1()`